# Multithreading of multiple files

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a java program that does this algorithm:

```
Given a directory.
For each file in the directory.
    read each line
        process the line with regex and other string operation in addition to parsing
        write the line after processing to an output file
```

The directory has around 10 files with around 3 million lines.

The processing part seems to be the bottleneck in the performance because of the regex complexity and the even slower with the parsing part.
since I have a powerful machine with plenty of ram and as consulted with "cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep processor | wc -l" contains 16 CPUs. It would be sad not to get these involved.

My idea is to first read all the files into a single array list. Then divide the list into sub array lists equal to the number of threads needed. After running the threads, each thread with the given sublist to do
the processing part concurrently and saving the output into new subarray which at the end should be merged and flushed into the output file.

Is this the right way of solving such a problem?

Any references to other similar works would be appreciated.

Many thanks.

```
    String dir = "path/to/dir";
    File folder = new File(dir);
    if (folder.isDirectory()) {
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
        for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
            File file = listOfFiles[i];
            if (file.isFile() && file.getName().contains("log")) {
                System.out.println("processing file: " + file);
                test.readFile(file);
            }
        }
    }
}

PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(output), StandardCharsets.UTF_8), true);
public void readFile(File file) {
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String line;

    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis,
                Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String processedLine = processingLine(line);
            if (processedLine != null){
                pw.println(processedLine);
            }

        }

    } catch (IOException e) {

    }
}

public String processingLine(String line) {
    //regex
    //string operations
    //parsing text
}
```

Comment: does each input file get it's own output file? or do they share 1 output file?

Comment: It would be a lot simpler to have the Java program process exactly 1 file sequentially, and start a copy of the program for each 10 files.

Comment: I'm quite surprised that parsing a line is so slow. What does the regex/parsing code look like? It seems you're recreting the same pattern every time the method is called (so, millions of times) instead of reusing it. That's a bad idea. For such code, if coded correctly, I would expect the IO to be the limiting factor. First hint: use a BufferedWriter.

Comment: How long is each line? Also, are these files stored on a single drive?

Comment: _"I would be grateful if someone can post a java code to implement this."_ ... sorry, but this is not how StackOverflow works.  You should read the [FAQ] and [Ask] for more information.  Hint: We don't write code for you wholesale.  _You_ attempt to solve the problem and then ask a question when you run into trouble.

Comment: You could use a Thread for each file, read each file and add its contents to a shared, blocking, queue. You could then use another series of threads to read from this queue and process the Strings, you'd probably need to put the result into another queue so you can control the writing of the output via a single Thread. This assumes that the order is unimportant...

Answer (score 0):

- Use java.util.concurrency.Executors to spawn child threads for each file processing;
- use synchronized queue to collect result;
- process collected queue in separate thread to write your data (safe & uncorrupted) into output.